# Strict (2048): Declaration of CsvImportBehavior::setup() should be compatible with ModelBehavior

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3, cakedc

I am getting the following error:

```
Strict (2048): Declaration of CsvImportBehavior::setup() should be compatible 
with ModelBehavior::setup(Model $model, $config = Array) 
[APP\Plugin\Utils\Model\Behavior\CsvImportBehavior.php, line 20]
```

I followed the tutorial on this site: http://www.pronique.com/blog/enable-csv-import-all-controllers-models-cakephp-2

When I import my CSV file, it gives the following flash message:

```
Successfully imported 0 records from Book1.csv
```

I don't understand why its not importing, does it have something to do with the error/warning its giving?

I looked inside the behaviour (CsvImportBehaviour.php at line 20): `class CsvImportBehavior extends ModelBehavior {`
That does not make sense on line 20, that's just the class declaration, so I moved down on the code and saw the following: `public function setup(Model &$Model, $settings = array()) {`-- this does seem to me to be according to the standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To suppress the errors/warnings, try to:

- remove the `&` before `$Model` (not required as Model is an object and therefore already passed *byref*)

*Optionally* (see comment by @mark):

- rename `$Model` to `$model` (lowercase)
- rename `$settings` to `$config`

I don't know the reason for not importing records from the CSV, that will require debugging on your side.

### Alternatives

CakePHP also has a `CSV dataSource` as part of the datasources plug in.

Using this, you can create a Model that, in stead of using a database, uses a CSV file as its source. This allows you to, for example, do this;

```
 $csvData = $this->MyCsvModel->find('all');
```

Which will return all rows from the CSV file. Importing this into your database will be easy to implement by saving `$csvData` to another model

Links:

https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/tree/2.0
https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/blob/2.0/Model/Datasource/CsvSource.php

Comment: the naming of the variables is irrelevant. it suffices to remove the `&` IMO.

Comment: @mark thanks, I wasn't behind my computer and not sure if it was also requiring the parameter _names_ to match for a compatible signature in strict mode (_personally_ I *hate it* if variable names are inconsistent, especially as `{@inheritdoc}` won't make any sense in your PhpDoc). I'll update my answer

Comment: You are right about that. It's all about consistency. Just saying :)

Comment: @mark Guess I'm more **strict** than *php-strict* is. I'll file a feature-request to add *php-fanatically-strict* mode :D

Comment: Hi guys, I removed the & before $Model and that removed the warning. thanks a lot.