# Declaration of ExtendAssociationsBehavior should be compatible with ModelBehavior

Tags: cakephp

I want to put a newsletter in my website and I am using the following plugin:

https://github.com/edap/cakephp-newsletter-plugin

I am getting the following error:

`Declaration of ExtendAssociationsBehavior::setup() should be compatible with ModelBehavior::setup(Model $model, $config = Array)`

How to solve this error

Comment: the plugin is no longer available

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict (2048): Declaration of CsvImportBehavior::setup() should be compatible with ModelBehavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091549/strict-2048-declaration-of-csvimportbehaviorsetup-should-be-compatible-wi)